# How can I make this code achieve the expected 7x speedup through parallelism?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm trying to do the first problem of the [first assignment from Stanford's CS 149](https://github.com/stanford-cs149/asst1#program-1-parallel-fractal-generation-using-threads-20-points). Note that I'm running on an i7 quad core Macbook Pro with hyperthreading enabled.

I initially tried the simple approach of having thread `i` operate on rows from `i/numThreads * height` to `i + 1 /numThreads * height`. I was unable to get more than a 2x speedup with this approach so I guessed that the issue was that my hardware caches were loading up entire lines of the `output` array. Because each thread was operating on its own line, every time the kernel switched from one thread to another, the new thread evicted the current line from the cache.

By modifying the signature of `mandelbrotSerial` to include a `stride` parameter I was then able to get to a ~4x speedup when running with 4 or more threads. The basic idea is to have threads operate on separate columns *within* each row to avoid cache thrashing.

```
void mandelbrotSerial(
    float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1,
    int width, int height,
    int startRow, int totalRows,
    int maxIterations,
    int output[], int stride, int startIdx)
{
    float dx = (x1 - x0) / width;
    float dy = (y1 - y0) / height;

    int endRow = startRow + totalRows;

    for (int j = startRow; j < endRow; j++) {
        for (int i = startIdx + 1; i < width; i+=stride) {
            float x = x0 + i * dx;
            float y = y0 + j * dy;

            int index = (j * width + i);
            output[index] = mandel(x, y, maxIterations);
        }
    }
}
```

I then added some timing code to my `workerThreadStart` function:

```
void workerThreadStart(WorkerArgs * const args) {
    double startTime = CycleTimer::currentSeconds();
    int stride = args->numThreads;
    int startIdx = args->threadId;
    mandelbrotSerial(
        args->x0,
        args->y0,
        args->x1,
        args->y1, args->width, args->height, 0, args->height, args->maxIterations, args->output, stride, startIdx);
    double endTime = CycleTimer::currentSeconds();
    printf("Hello world from thread %d, stride %d, startIdx %d, time %f\n", args->threadId, stride, startIdx, endTime-startTime);
}
```

I noticed an interesting pattern where most of the threads where all but one of the threads were achieving ~70 ms runtimes:

```
Hello world from thread 2, stride 8, startIdx 2, time 0.070486
Hello world from thread 4, stride 8, startIdx 4, time 0.070031
Hello world from thread 3, stride 8, startIdx 3, time 0.070382
Hello world from thread 5, stride 8, startIdx 5, time 0.070693
Hello world from thread 1, stride 8, startIdx 1, time 0.072447
Hello world from thread 7, stride 8, startIdx 7, time 0.070525
Hello world from thread 6, stride 8, startIdx 6, time 0.070549
Hello world from thread 0, stride 8, startIdx 0, time 0.103877
```

so I guessed that the first thread was unluckily being required to warm up the cache for the other threads. I tried to get around this problem by using the first thread *only* to warm up the cache:

```
void workerThreadStart(WorkerArgs * const args) {
    double startTime = CycleTimer::currentSeconds();
    int stride = args->threadId == 0 ? args->width / args -> numThreads : args->numThreads - 1;
    int startIdx = args->threadId;
    mandelbrotSerial(
        args->x0,
        args->y0,
        args->x1,
        args->y1, args->width, args->height, 0, args->height, args->maxIterations, args->output, stride, startIdx);
    double endTime = CycleTimer::currentSeconds();
    printf("Hello world from thread %d, stride %d, startIdx %d, time %f\n", args->threadId, stride, startIdx, endTime-startTime);
}
```

With this approach I consistently get speedups around 5.2x:

```
Hello world from thread 0, stride 200, startIdx 0, time 0.004734
Hello world from thread 4, stride 7, startIdx 4, time 0.086578
Hello world from thread 1, stride 7, startIdx 1, time 0.089177
Hello world from thread 3, stride 7, startIdx 3, time 0.091931
Hello world from thread 2, stride 7, startIdx 2, time 0.092376
Hello world from thread 5, stride 7, startIdx 5, time 0.092791
Hello world from thread 7, stride 7, startIdx 7, time 0.094090
Hello world from thread 6, stride 7, startIdx 6, time 0.094883
[mandelbrot thread]:            [91.795] ms
Wrote image file mandelbrot-thread.ppm
                                (5.28x speedup from 8 threads)
```

The `mandelbrotThread` method looks like this:

```
//
// MandelbrotThread --
//
// Multi-threaded implementation of mandelbrot set image generation.
// Threads of execution are created by spawning std::threads.
void mandelbrotThread(
    int numThreads,
    float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1,
    int width, int height,
    int maxIterations, int output[])
{
    static constexpr int MAX_THREADS = 32;

    if (numThreads > MAX_THREADS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Max allowed threads is %d\n", MAX_THREADS);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Creates thread objects that do not yet represent a thread.
    std::thread workers[MAX_THREADS];
    WorkerArgs args[MAX_THREADS];

    for (int i=0; i<numThreads; i++) {
      
        // TODO FOR CS149 STUDENTS: You may or may not wish to modify
        // the per-thread arguments here.  The code below copies the
        // same arguments for each thread
        args[i].x0 = x0;
        args[i].y0 = y0;
        args[i].x1 = x1;
        args[i].y1 = y1;
        args[i].width = width;
        args[i].height = height;
        args[i].maxIterations = maxIterations;
        args[i].numThreads = numThreads;
        args[i].output = output;
      
        args[i].threadId = i;
    }

    // Spawn the worker threads.  Note that only numThreads-1 std::threads
    // are created and the main application thread is used as a worker
    // as well.
    for (int i=1; i<numThreads; i++) {
        workers[i] = std::thread(workerThreadStart, &args[i]);
    }
    
    workerThreadStart(&args[0]);

    // join worker threads
    for (int i=1; i<numThreads; i++) {
        workers[i].join();
    }
}
```

I worry I've gone on the wrong track because the assignment clearly states "Hint: There is a very simple static assignment that will achieve this goal, and no communication/synchronization among threads is necessary."

I'd welcome any tips on how to better approach the problem.

Comment: Where is your thread start in your code, I would advise you to have a look at [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) in this case each thread will return a chunk of data. The 7x speedup might be a bit optimistic. Your threads take startup time so you need to a lot of calculations on one thread to make that overhead insignificant. For passing data to std::async/std::thread use [lambda expressions/functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: Also whatever or whoever is learning you C++ is doing it learning you "C" style coding instead which I think is an outdated approach.

Comment: Seems like a problem where `std::for_each(std::execution::par, ...);` would come in handy - except that would take _all_ available threads :)

Comment: Added the main method to the question. One thing they do in the problem set is to use the main thread as a worker thread. I notice that if I instead start a separate "0" thread using std::thread then the penalty for thread 0 goes away, so I can get to 5.2x speedup with the first approach I listed

Comment: @PepijnKramer This is not a C++ course. Not every course that uses C++ teaches C++.

Comment: What if `totalRows` <= 0? That doesn't seem safe.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit I know but IMO if they use C++ they should. Otherwise they should use "C".  But that's an opinion based discussion best not done here ;)

Comment: I advise you to use OpenMP for such a task (this is a standard for high-performance computing codes). Mandelbrot is an example with a need for work load-balancing between thread since some parts of the image need more iterations than others. This can be done easily using *tasks* and an *over-decomposition* using OpenMP. Using plain C++ this is a bit tedious since you have to reimplement a pool of threads executing tasks and scheduling small tasks efficiently turns out not so easy, especially in non-trivial architecture or when they are dependencies (people do PhD thesis on this subject).

Comment: Here for mandelbrot, an efficient approach is to divide the image in many small part (eg. lines) where each threads is responsible for a contiguous number of line and can also execute some task of other thread thanks to a *work-stealing* algorithm. The best approach is to pre-balance the number parts and their size based on an heavy grained sampling so to predict the computational cost of the parts. However, this last strategy is quite complex to implement. Besides, good work stealing strategy can actually be very good on shared-memory ~UMA architectures (eg. low-end Intel/AMD CPUs)

Comment: Read farther down in the assignment... "Note the similarity to Program 1, where you statically assigned parts of the image to threads."  This may be a clue about the hint in assignment 1.  (In part 3 of the assignment)

Comment: Run it on a machine with 7x more threads or 7x higher clock speed 

Answer (score 0):

Very simple but not-so-efficient approach would be this:

```
(measure)iterate a pixel's value for 5 times

if completed
    write the color to target buffer directly
if not complete
    mark the pixel as "heavy work"
```

then sort(or just separate into 2 arrays) the pixels on their "heavy work" status (making all similar pixels neighboring while remembering their positions on image output).

Then launch N threads on the "heavy work" region of sorted pixels. The rest of pixels are already computed by measurement phase.

Possible improvements:

- multithreaded measurement (requires no communication)
- - because if average iterations per pixel is about 20 iterations, then just 1 measurement thread can have at most 4x speedup due to the minimum 5 iterations measurement per pixel.
- - 8 measurement threads should make the easy pixels 8x faster but the important part is "heavy work" pixels and those need equal balance between threads, so there is "compacting/sorting" of all heavy-work pixels for efficient static work-distribution among 8 threads
- SIMD-friendly calculation order for even more than 7x (perhaps 20x-30x) speedup
- use 2D tiling instead of scan-line work distribution. 2D tiles tend to have easier measurement of performance (i.e. measure just 4 corners of tile & mark the whole tile as "heavy work" = better work scheduling for threads)
- - sorting tiles = less elements (thousands) to sort than pixels (millions)
- - suits better to SIMD work because more of SIMD lanes would be doing similar amount of work

---

If thread-thread communication was allowed, simple atomic incrementing would be enough to distribute scanlines between threads for a good speedup.